# Doesn't GIT support some way of down revving?

Tags: git

After a pull/fetch, the code won't build. I just want to revert to a version that I know built correctly. Looking at the documentation, and doing web searches, I have not found an answer to this REALLY basic question. If I know a version of the code from the past built, do I have to delete my current clone, and redo the clone altogether? How do I specify which version I want to "pull" in the clone command?

I hate GIT.

Comment: Please go read basic docs about how to use git (any tutorial should do). The `checkout` command is well documented.

Comment: Don't hate something you clearly know nothing about.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let me recommend the excellent [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2); if you take the time to read it and go through some sample exercises, you will save yourself a *lot* of pain in the future. Trust me, you think you hate git now? There are a lot of nasty surprises in store for you if you don't get a firm foundation.

Anyway, on to the problem at hand. Assuming the last correctly build code was at commit `abc123`, simply do `git checkout abc123`. Now your working copy will match what was at that commit. If you have no plans on modifying that snapshot of the code, that is all you need to do.

However, if you *do* want to modify the code, you are going to want to do so on a branch. Let's say you want to call the branch "myBranch". Type `git checkout abc123 -b myBranch`, which will create `myBranch` at that commit and switch you to it. Then your future commits will be on that branch. Once you are done, you will want to merge `myBranch` into the main branch; assuming the main branch is `master`, you would do `git checkout master` followed by `git merge myBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't work the way you may be used to from e.g. Subversion. When you clone, you don't just get the current version, you get all versions. Because of that, it doesn't make sense to specify the version you want to clone. You *already* have the version you want on your local system, just not in a format you can read. You merely need to "check out" that version.

Ordinarily I might suggest the commands you need to run to achieve that, but from your question, I get the impression that it would be better to start with a GUI that lets you see the history, lets you pick a specific commit, and lets you check out that version. This is core functionality and almost all GUIs support it directly in a reasonably intuitive manner. The reason I suggest a GUI is that getting visual feedback of the result of your checkout may give you a better understanding of what Git is doing.

Answer (score -1):

A co-worker explained the syntax I needed to use. I still have found no documentation of this syntax, anywhere. Maybe it's specific to this particular environment, I don't know. It is just "git checkout r1234". Simple. Don't I feel the fool.